# sum of Duplicates records in union

Tags: php, sql, group-by, sum, where-clause

I need to get sum of all duplicates records where item_name and extra is same then sum the quantity.
here is my code.

```
    $query_or1="select * from invoice_client where order_id='$order1'
    
       UNION all
       select * from invoice_client where order_id='$order2'
       UNION all
       select * from invoice_client where order_id='$order3'
       UNION all
       select * from invoice_client where order_id='$order4'
       UNION    all 
       select * from invoice_client where order_id='$order5'
       ORDER BY extra, item_name
       ";**
```

// Display the result using following code
echo

```
                  **echo 
                  "<tr>
                  
                  <td>".$result_or1['inv_id']."</td>
                  
                    <td>".$result_or1['item_name']."</td>
                    <td>".$result_or1['extra']."</td>
                    <td>".$result_or1['quantity']."</td>
                    <td>".$get_wet*$result_or1['quantity']."</td>
                      
                                      </tr>";**
```

Comment: Why is this using UNIONs in the first place? This should be _one_ SELECT statement, with `WHERE order_id IN (…, …)`

Comment: And then, you might want to look into GROUP BY and aggregate functions.

Comment: You need to become aware that it's possible for the `WHERE` section of the query to contain more than one criteria!

Answer (score 0):

It *looks like* you want a `where` clause with an `in` condition, then aggregation:

```
select extra, item_name, sum(quantity) sum_quantity
from invoice_client
where corder_id in (?, ?, ?, ?)
group by extra, item_name
order by extra, item_name
```

Note that I used `?` to represent the parameters to the query; you should really used prepared statements rather than concatenating variables in the query string: this makes your code safer, and more efficient.